# Unable to Creating Executable Jar in Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, jar

I have a spring project which I connect to mongodb to do some CRUD operations. I have built my project in Netbeans and it works fine but when I want to make the executable jar file,  I compile the project with `mvn package  with no error. my jar file execute util to the line

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/SpringConfig.xml");
```

but from the line above I have got this error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [spring/SpringConfig.xml]
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
>   .....

This is part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>mehdi</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.faracloud.runner.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

also, this is the spring configuration file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="192.168.1.5" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="mydb" mongo-ref="mongo" username="user1"
    password="1234" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

Best to Experts

Answer (score 1):

How do you define mongo drivers in project? Also by maven?

If you have a file (probably mehdi-jar-with-dependecies.jar) Try to open it, (jar is a file in zip format, so this is just unpack) and locate if necessary drivers/classes are there.

Probably mongo drivers are available in Netbeans, but not present in Jar file.

Comment: how to make available them?

Comment: Try with update of  spring-data-mongodb dependency, try to modify Jar file or specify additional classpath with this project. If you are sure that something is missing in jar then maybe other dependencies are missing.  In this case try using maven shade-plugin. Your issue is really similar to other typical dependency problems like: http://www.baeldung.com/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-for-xml-schema-namespace

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin and problem solved :

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>xxx.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>xxx.App</mainClass>  

                    </program>                      
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```